# Using blender for images- OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm writing an application in OpenCV- C Api. I want to somewhat blend 2 IplImages together. I looked at the blender functions which are in C++ so I've tried converting in order to use this function.

```
void detail::Blender( A, B, 50);
```

Where:

```
Mat A (imgYellowThresh1,true);
Mat B (imgblueThresh, true);
```

It's telling me that `detail` should have a `_` in front then when changed returns further errors. Any examples or advice on what else I can use would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The Blender class is a bit more complex. Unless you desire the advanced blending features, an `AddWeighted` is an easy but versatile way to blend two images:

```
IplImage* A=cvLoadImage("Cup.jpg", 1);
IplImage* B=cvLoadImage("NoCup.jpg", 1);
IplImage* Destination=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(A), IPL_DEPTH_16U, 3);

double alpha = 0.5;
double beta = 0.5;
double gamma = 0.0; //offset 

cvAddWeighted(A,alpha,B,beta,gamma,Destination);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! the effect works really well. The only thing is I can't use cvFlip  in order to draw on a black screen instead of the video. So I used cvAddWeighted(frame,alpha,frame,beta,gamma, frame); then cvFlip(imgscribble, frame,1);  //the flip normally changes the video from cam to black screen

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `flip`: with `cvFlip(imgscribble, frame,1);` you are overwriting the image that you just generated; `frame` is now the mirror image of `imgscribble`.

Comment: frame is input from camera used to track colours in order to draw cvlines.  imgScribble holds the line data. I changed the cvAddWeighted(frame,alpha,frame,beta,gamma,imgScribble ) which draws the lines on a white background and the blending is working but the lines now fly around instead of drawing from point A to B.

Comment: It's hard to tell without the code, but maybe you have an offset in your ROIs (if you are using any), or an operation like `cvFlip()` or `cvResize()`... take a look at your code and you will find it.